# No me funciona el operador ||

Tags: javascript, operador

Soy nuevo aprendiendo JavaScript y estoy haciendo prácticas pero no me sale bien esto:

```
var estatura = 1.70 var edad2 = 30

if( edad2 == 30 || estatura = 1.60){
    document. write("true");} else{
    document.write("false");}
```

Me lo marca como error en la consola del navegador, ¿por qué?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar que error te arroja?

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta en el enlace y agregar el error que te esta dando

Comment: **Parece ser un problema que contiene errores tipográficos.**

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, yo lo llamaría un error de sintaxis. De aquellos que uno comete cuando recién está aprendiendo, ya sabes, confundir asignación con comparación. Pero, vamos, si va contra las reglas del sitio, habrá que cerrarlo

Comment: @César viendo que el comparador lo usa y luego usa la asignacion, pienso que si fuer error tipografico porque conoce la caracteristica de comparar. Si ambos fueran el de asignacion, dudaria en si conoce o no la sintaxis. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b de acuerdo.

Answer (score 1):

mira este es la solucion te falto un `=` y un cerrar las variables con `;`

```js
var estatura = 1.70;
var edad2 = 30;

if( edad2 == 30 || estatura == 1.60){
document.write("true");
} else{ 
document.write("false");
}
```

Comment: el signo de punto y coma no causa ese error al menos no en JS y no es necesario

Answer (score 1):

Saludos te hace falta otro signo de igual dentro de la comparación que haces en el if:

```
    var estatura = 1.70
    var edad2 = 30

if( edad2 === 30 || estatura === 1.60)
{
    console.log("true");
} else{
    console.log("false");    
}
```

acuerdate que si solo usas un signo de igual le estas indicando a la variable que tomará ese valor mientras que si usas doble signo de igual le indicas que compare si posee ese valor y si le pones triple signo igual a parte le pides que verifique si el tipo de dato es el mismo.

Te devolverá true por que aunque la segunda comparación es falsa, la primera es verdadera y el operador que estás usando verifica que con alguna de las dos condiciones que se cumpla de verdadero

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en la segunda parte del condicional. Tienes que usar doble `==` para que funcione:

```
if (edad2 == 30 || estatura == 1.60){ document.write("true")("true");} else { document.write("true")("false");}
```

Se usa un solo `=` para asignación.

Por otro lado, si vas a hacer una asignación doble en la misma línea tienes que separarlos por `;`:

```
> var estatura = 1.70; var edad2 = 30;
> estatura
1.7
> edad2
30
```

O, en su defecto, usar una `,` para separar las expresiones:

```
> var estatura = 1.70, var edad2 = 30;
> estatura
1.7
> edad2
30
```

Ambas funcionan.

Si estás probando código en la consola del navegador (lo más facil para practicarlo), entonces puedes usar multilínea apretando <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, de esa forma se ve más ordenado y puedes practicar mejor sin romperte la cabeza leyendo todo en la misma línea:

```
> var estatura = 1.70; var edad2 = 30;
> if( edad2 == 30 || estatura == 1.60){ // Shift + Enter
    console.log("true");                // Shift + Enter
  } else {                              // Shift + Enter
    console.log("false");               // Shift + Enter
  }                                     // Enter
true
>
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo aquí mi respuesta :)

```
     var estatura = 1.70; //Cuando es asignación solo se utiliza un "="
     var edad2 = 30;
     //También debes finalizar las variables con ";"
     if( edad2 == 30 || estatura == 1.60) //Cuando utilizas condicionales siempre es doble "=" 
     {
      document.write("true"); //Tenías un espacio después del document
     } 
     else
     {
     document.write("false");
     }
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, agrega una explicación de lo que agregas como respuesta, revisar [answer], saludos.